# Ubuntu ENV Variable not loaded in Jupyter Python os.environ

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have setup in command line this variable :

```
  export DIRCWD=/myfolder/
```

Here :

```
   ./.bashrc
   /etc/profile
```

In Jupyter notebook cell, am doing

```
  import os; os.environ
```

I could not see it.... after rebooting the machine...

echo $DIRCWD is working and showing values.

In shelll :

```
Python
import os; os.environ is working....
```

**Question :**
   Where os.environ is taking their values ?

EDIT:
Jupyter notebook is launched at start under (root) :

```
@reboot sleep 5 &&  jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888
```

It seems not loading .bashrc profile ....

Comment: have you restarted jupyter after setting the variable in your profile/shell? propagation of variables is done from parent to child, not otherwise

Comment: yes, reboot the linux machine...

Comment: when you're launching Jupyter, are you in a terminal? if so, do you see the variable defined in this terminal? If not, then it's not a jupyter issue.

Comment: In jupyter, am executing  print(os.environ)

Comment: I mean _before_ launching jupyter. Do you type the jupyter command somewhere in a shell? that's where you should check env. vars. `os.environ` works all right.

Comment: yes, jupyter is launche through command line in bash..... (looks obvious)

Comment: ok, then what does `echo $DIRCWD` give you in that bash? sorry for the obvious, but what's obvious for me is that `os.environ` works. you could have clicked on some desktop icon or whatever. I'm not running linux myself.

Comment: Did you try on Jupyter notebook or in bash shell>python ?

Comment: Might I suggest you back up here and ask the OS itself which environment variables are defined for that interpreter? Find its pid, and inspect `/proc/PID/environ`. (The file is NUL-delimited, but `tr '\0' '\n' </proc/PID/environ`, putting the actual number in place of `PID`, will replace those NULs with newlines).

Comment: It's absolutely possible for processes to override their environments such as to not copy variables from their parent, but if you've got a program written to do that, it's that program's fault -- ie. it's explicitly and intentionally not propagating the variable you want.

Comment: related to Jupyter notebook ?

Comment: Jupyter notebook is a process among others. It is not special. You must be running it from a shell which doesn't parse the shell profile(s) where you have set your variables. Just _check the variables in the shell before you run Jupyter_...

Comment: Can you read correctly my question ?

Comment: @Tensor, if you had answered the question Jean-François Fabre was asking (checking whether the variable is set *in the same shell that starts Jupyter Notebook*), it would have saved us a lot of trouble. That said, I think you've added enough to provide an answer now. BTW, running this as root is a **huge** security hole.

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming that this is a `fcron` job specification:

```
@reboot sleep 5 &&  jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888
```

**Shells started by `fcron`, like other noninteractive shells, do not read dotfiles automatically.** If you want to force this to happen, you need to make it explicit:

```
@reboot sleep 5; . /etc/profile && jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888
```

Comment: Thx, how to launch jupyter as a username ?

Comment: @Tensor, the best-practice approach depends on your operating system and what tools it provides. On a systemd-based distro, for instance, I'd use a [systemd user service](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User). On a distro using runit, I'd put [chpst](http://smarden.org/runit/chpst.8.html) in the run script. On a Mac, I'd want a [launchd user agent](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html). Figuring out what's appropriate for you is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: That means a systemd user service is probably the right thing (for current versions; for an older one, you might use Upstart instead).